# TEXCOORD0 vs COLOR in a Cg shader

Tags: shaders, panda3d, cg

I started to learn Cg shader programming, following the Panda3d shader tutorials. Having a scene with only a cube shown, each vertex of the model with a different color, I can successfully use the following shader:

```
void vshader(
    uniform float4x4 mat_modelproj,
    in float4 vtx_position : POSITION,
    in float4 vtx_color : COLOR,
    out float4 l_color : COLOR,
    out float4 l_position : POSITION)
{
    l_position = mul(mat_modelproj, vtx_position);
    l_color = vtx_color;
}

void fshader(
    in float4 l_color : COLOR,
    out float4 o_color : COLOR)
{
    o_color = l_color;
}
```

This works fine, I can see the colors on the cube interpolated between the vertices, based on the color values of the vertices set in to the cube model.

Now I changed that shader a bit to the following:

```
void vshader(
    uniform float4x4 mat_modelproj,
    in float4 vtx_position : POSITION,
    in float4 vtx_color : COLOR,
    out float4 l_my : TEXCOORD0,
    out float4 l_position : POSITION)
{
    l_position = mul(mat_modelproj, vtx_position);
    l_my = vtx_color;
}

void fshader(
    in float4 l_my : TEXCOORD0,
    out float4 o_color : COLOR)
{
    o_color = l_my;
}
```

However, using this custom variable `l_my` the coloring of the cube does not work correctly any more. Instead of the interpolated vertices colors I only see the default gray-ish color on the whole cube.

I understand that in the second example `l_my` is a `TEXCOORD0` instead of a `COLOR`, but isn't it still a normal `float4` value?

PS: it works again fine if I change `l_my` to `COLOR` -- but why does that solve the problem, if in both cases its of type `float4`?

Comment: Can you change the title to represent the actual issue you're facing?

Comment: Changing `COLOR` to `TEXCOORD0` shouldn't have any effect, except that (IIRC) `COLOR` is clamped to [0, 1] before interpolation, and `TEXCOORD0` isn't.

Comment: Well, there is no longer any vertex color output at all.  Your cube may be _uncolored_ (colored black).  Try outputting a constant white `COLOR` from the vertex shader and see if that helps.

Comment: @bobobobo But he's reading the color from `TEXCOORD0` in the fragment shader.

Comment: I know, but I'm concerned _not_ outputting a _vertex_ color from the vertex shader somewhere along the way says "this vertex has no color" and possibly just sets it black (either multiplying the output of the pixel shader by black, or not even evaluating the :COLOR output of the fragment shader).

Comment: @bobobobo No, it doesn't work that way. Vertex shader outputs just communicate to the fragment shader; aside from `POSITION`, they don't have any special meaning.

Comment: I have changed the title of the question and also added some more info (see PS line).

Comment: One thing you could check is whether this issue varies from profile to profile - ie, try comparing the result with arbfp1/arbvp1 vs glslf/glslv.